# observer design pattern question

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, observer-pattern

i am creating a oop system in php and would like to implement more observer patterns into it as i have heavy coupling between my classes that i wish to reduce.

my question is this.
in relation to best practice in design for this pattern is it ok for one class to add an observer to another class, that class is working with.
or should i keep the observer adding to the top most level of the chain?

example: (assume other methods called, but not included in the class, exist but are not important for this example.)

```
class orderItem extends observable {
     public function pick($qty, $user){
          $this->setUser($user);
          $position = new position($this->getPositionID());
          $position->addObserver(new ProductObserver());  // is this the best option ? ?
          $position->setQty($position->getQty() - $qty);
          $position->save();
          $this->notify(self::EVENT_PICK); // notify observers
     }
}

class orderProductObserver implements observer {
     public function update($orderitem){
           $position = new position($orderitem->getPositionID());
           $product = new product($position->getProductID());
           if($product->getQty() < $product->getMinimum()) {
                $alert = new minProductAlert($product);
           }
     }
}

class ProductObserver implements observer {
     public function update($position){
           $product = new product($position->getProductID());
           if($product->getQty() < $product->getMinimum()) {
                $alert = new minProductAlert($product);
           }
     }
}

$order = new orderItem(123);
$order->addObserver(new orderProductObserver()); // or is this the best option ??
$order->pick(2, 'bill');
```

Or alternatively if both methods are wrong i am very interested in your input.

would this example be the most ideal by removing dependency between orderitem and position ?

```
 class OrderItem extends Observable {
         public function pick($qty, $user){
              $this->setUser($user);
              $this->setPickedQty($qty);
              $this->save();
              $this->notify(self::EVENT_PICK); // notify observers
         }
    }

    class OrderItemPickObserver implements Observer {
         public function update($orderitem){
               $position = new Position($orderitem->getPositionID());
               $position->addObserver(new ProductPositionObserver());
               $position->setQty($position->getQty() - $orderItem->getPickedQty());
               $position->save();
         }
    }

    class ProductPositionObserver implements Observer {
         public function update($position){
               $product = new product($position->getProductID());
               if($product->getQty() < $product->getMinimum()) {
                    $alert = new minProductAlert($product);
               }
         }
    }
    $pickQty = 2;
    $orderitem = new OrderItem(123);
    $position = new Position($orderitem->getPositionID());
    if($position->getQty() >= $pickQty)
    {
           $orderitem->addObserver(new OrderItemPickObserver()); // or is this the best option ??
           $orderitem->pick($pickQty, 'bill');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second example looks good, but I'm not sure if creating new `Position` object inside update method of `OrderItemPickObserver` class. Instead, what I would suggest is to keep a `Position` object as a property of `OrderItem` class so that you can set it from outside.

```
class OrderItem extends Observable {
         private $_position;
         public function setPosition($position){
              $this->_position = $position;
         }  
         public function getPosition(){
              return $this->_position;
         }  
    }
```

Then update `OrderItemPickObserver` class:

```
class OrderItemPickObserver implements Observer {
         public function update($orderitem){
               $position = $orderitem->getPosition());
               $position->setQty($position->getQty() - $orderItem->getPickedQty());
               $position->save();
         }
    }
```

And your calling code:

```
$orderitem = new OrderItem(123);    
$position = new Position();
$position->addObserver(new ProductPositionObserver());
$orderitem->setPosition($position);
```

This way you can decouple `OrderItemPickObserver` and `Position` classes.

EDITED:

If your business logic doesn't allow you to have a `Position` object in `OrderItem` class, you can move the same to `OrderItemPickObserver` since this is the class which actually uses the `Position` object.

```
class OrderItemPickObserver implements Observer {
             private $_position;
             function __construct($position){
                  $this->_position = $position;
             }  

             public function update($orderitem){
                   $position = $this->_position;
                   $position->setId($orderitem->getPositionID());
                   $position->setQty($position->getQty() - $orderItem->getPickedQty());
                   $position->save();
             }
        }
```

And your calling code:

```
$orderitem = new OrderItem(123);    
$position = new Position();
$position->addObserver(new ProductPositionObserver());
...
...
$orderitem->addObserver(new OrderItemPickObserver($position));
```

Comment: something i did not mention before but orderItem represents the following mysql table row
columns include
positionID : reference to the position being edited
qty
qtypicked
user

when the object its constructed it grabs the mysql row data and exists as a wrapper around that (for validating and record specific methods)

how would i add the position from outside the class removing the dependancy but still maintain a linked business logic?

Comment: ha.. or i could decouple the creation of the object to a factory class that injects the required objects in.

Comment: Or you can use the approach in EDIT if that fits.

Answer (score 0):

I would use your second method .... its a lot clearer to read and understand than the first (dependency injection)- good examples (although an old document) are given here -> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/

Comment: i added another example could i get your thoughts on this ?